# Why is my function firing before the onclick is clicked?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

This is my code below. My getQuote keeps firing before the button is clicked. It fires immediately when the page loads. It's strange to me, any ideas why?

```
function _(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
var html = "";
const newQuote = document.getElementById("submit");
const tweet = _("tweet-quote");
var tweetURL = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=RonSwanson&text=";

newQuote.onclick = getQuote();

//Get Quote Function

function getQuote() {
  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://ron-swanson-quotes.herokuapp.com/v2/quotes')
  ourRequest.onload = () => {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    quoteText = ourData[0];
    html = "<i class='fas fa-quote-left'></i>"
    html += ourData[0] + "<i class='fas fa-quote-right'></i>";
    html += "<br><br>" + "<p class='text-right'> -Ron Swanson</p>";
    _("quote").innerHTML = html;
    tweet.setAttribute('href', tweetURL + encodeURIComponent('"' + quoteText + '"') + encodeURIComponent("-Ron Swanson"));
  }
  ourRequest.send();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:
newQuote.onclick = getQuote();

to this:
newQuote.onclick = getQuote;

Comment: To elaborate on this. The reason why the function is firing is that `()` essentially means call (or fire) this function. Removing them as the answer suggests (`newQuote.onclick = getQuote`) is saying assign your getQuote function to newQuote.onclick

Comment: Holy Cow! I can't believe I didn't know this all this time, thank you so much guys!